# Swagger UI 403 Forbidden on Production after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` `6.1.4` installed on an `Asp.Net 5.0` WebApi.

The API is protected using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` `5.0.6`.

I have a `LoginController` with a `HTTPPOST` endpoint `[AllowAnonymous]` filter added to generate the initial JWT.

When running locally, I can call this using Swagger UI and generate a token. However, if I publish to our pre-production server for further tests, we are getting a `403 Forbidden` error when calling the login endpoint through swagger? I can call it successfully through Postman though.

The `swagger ui` is configured as follows int eh `Startup.cs`;

```
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Services.WebApi", Version = "v2" });

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

                var securitySchema = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\".",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                };

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securitySchema);

                var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    { securitySchema, new[] { "Bearer" } }
                };

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);
            });
```

and then in the `Configure` method;

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors();
        }  
      
       app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Services.WebApi ASP NET Core 5 v2"));
```

Can anyone advise what the issue could be?

**EDIT**

I can also confirm that if I generate a JWT through postman (to the pre-production server URL), and then add this to the Swagger UI authorization at the top of the UI;

1. Calling one of the HTTPGGET endpoints returns successfully
2. Calling the POST api/login endpoint fails still (though the JWT is added to this).

Comment: Could you show us the middlewares called before the app.UseSwagger?

Comment: yes no problem will update now

Comment: Ok, I worked it out from the network output. Swagger was by default adding `Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true` to the request (which is working locally). But on the preproduction server causes the 403. Changing this to `Content-Type: application/json` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help too :)